# Sorting an array by category names

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

Given this array `a`:

```
a = [
    {id: 3, category_name: "Horror"},
    {id: 4, category_name: "Non-Fiction"},
    {id: 5, category_name: "LGBT"},
    {id: 6, category_name: "Romance"},
    {id: 7, category_name: "Romance"}
]
```

I would like a way to order the objects in the array `a` by category names using the order of the array (indices), as Ruby arrays luckily are ordered arrays by default:

```
categories_sorted = [
   "Romance",
   "LGBT",
   "Non-Fiction",
   "Horror"
]
```

So that the sorting algorithm would give me an array that would look like this:

```
result = [
    {id: 6, category_name: "Romance"},
    {id: 7, category_name: "Romance"},
    {id: 5, category_name: "LGBT"},
    {id: 4, category_name: "Non-Fiction"},
    {id: 3, category_name: "Horror"}
]
```

Can you point out any ways to achieve this efficiently?
The array "a" could be as big as 20 objects, and the sorted categories can have as much as 30 categories in my scenario.

Comment: Generally an "array" is ordered, but a "set" isn't. Same holds true in Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worth compiling a sort index list to avoid having to look things up constantly:

```
categories_sorted_index = Hash[
  categories_sorted.each_with_index.collect do |name, index|
    [ name, index ]
  end
]

a.sort_by do |entry|
  categories_sorted_index[entry[:category_name]] || 0
end

# =>
# {:id=>7, :category_name=>"Romance"}
# {:id=>6, :category_name=>"Romance"}
# {:id=>5, :category_name=>"LGBT"}
# {:id=>4, :category_name=>"Non-Fiction"}
# {:id=>3, :category_name=>"Horror"}
```

Answer (score 3):

do as below :-

```
a = [
    {id: 3, category_name: "Horror"},
    {id: 4, category_name: "Non-Fiction"},
    {id: 5, category_name: "LGBT"},
    {id: 6, category_name: "Romance"},
    {id: 7, category_name: "Romance"}
]

categories_sorted = [
   "Romance",
   "LGBT",
   "Non-Fiction",
   "Horror"
]

p a.sort_by { |h| [categories_sorted.index(h[:category_name]), h[:id]] }
# >> [{:id=>6, :category_name=>"Romance"}, {:id=>7, :category_name=>"Romance"}, {:id=>5, :category_name=>"LGBT"}, {:id=>4, :category_name=>"Non-Fiction"}, {:id=>3, :category_name=>"Horror"}]
```

Comment: Wow. That is impressive. Such a good use of `sort_by`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way that uses [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) and [Hash#values_at](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) rather than [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by):

```
a.group_by { |h| h[:category_name] }.values_at(*categories_sorted).flatten
  #=> [{:id=>6, :category_name=>"Romance"},
  #    {:id=>7, :category_name=>"Romance"},
  #    {:id=>5, :category_name=>"LGBT"},
  #    {:id=>4, :category_name=>"Non-Fiction"},
  #    {:id=>3, :category_name=>"Horror"}]
```

Comment: oh,[values_at] can be used as such.